# QuickBlox Android NoResponse

Tags: java, chat, quickblox

I'm developing a simple Android based chat application using QuickBlox. For that I have created a Quickblox Free account. Now sometimes when I try to login to the chat service I get following error. Any idea on this ?

```
03-15 15:58:37.589  15897-16016/com.ne.chatapp D/QBASDK﹕ Connecting to chat..
03-15 15:58:43.499  15897-16020/com.ne.chatapp D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <stream:stream to="chat.quickblox.com" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0">
03-15 15:58:48.380  15897-16020/com.ne.chatapp D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): </stream:stream>
03-15 15:58:48.390  15897-16016/com.ne.chatapp E/Login error1﹕ NoResponseException
03-15 15:58:48.420  15897-15897/com.ne.chatapp E/Login error﹕ NoResponseException
```

Java code for user authentication

```
public void AuthenticateUser(String Email,String Password,final Context context)
{
    loginActivity = (LoginActivity)context;
    applicationSingleton = (ApplicationSingleton)loginActivity.getApplication();

    QBChatService.setDebugEnabled(true);
    QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(GlobalData.APP_ID, GlobalData.AUTH_KEY, GlobalData.AUTH_SECRET);
    if (!QBChatService.isInitialized()) {
        QBChatService.init(context);
    }
    chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();

    final QBUser user = new QBUser();
    user.setLogin(Email);
    user.setPassword(Password);

    QBAuth.createSession(user, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBSession>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBSession session, Bundle args) {
            user.setId(session.getUserId());
            applicationSingleton.setCurrentUser(user);

            if(chatService.isLoggedIn())
            {
                applicationSingleton.setLoginType(LoginType.UNKNOWN);
                loginActivity.onLoginSuccess();
                return;
            }


            chatService.login(user, new QBEntityCallbackImpl() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    try {
                        chatService.startAutoSendPresence(GlobalData.AUTO_PRESENCE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS);
                        applicationSingleton.setChatService(chatService);
                        applicationSingleton.setLoginType(LoginType.NORMAL);
                        loginActivity.onLoginSuccess();

                    } catch (SmackException.NotLoggedInException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(List errors) {
                    Log.e("Login error1", errors.get(0).toString());
                    loginActivity.onLoginError(errors);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> errors) {
            Log.e("Session : ", errors.get(0).toString());
            loginActivity.onLoginError(errors);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is ok. Perhaps it was related with problems on internet connection or XMPP servers.

How often does this problem reproduce\appear in app
Could you reproduce this bug by yourself, if you could please describe the steps to reproduce this bug below?

Comment: Thank you for the respond. You are correct. Its nothing to do with the code. It works perfectly with mobile data on. Problem comes when I switch to the wifi. I tested this with several other devices and its working fine.

Comment: Quick Blox has lot of limitations

Answer (score 0):

In timeout case, you can increase timeout by

```
final static int TIME_OUT=100000;
QBChatService.setDefaultPacketReplyTimeout(TIME_OUT);
```